# clockwise numbering of subfigures

Tags: formatting, numbering, subfloats

LaTeX always gives you

```
| Subfigure 1 | Subfigure 2 |

| Subfigure 3 | Subfigure 4 |
```

but I'd like to get

```
| Subfigure 1 | Subfigure 2 |

| Subfigure 4 | Subfigure 3 |
```

Comment: First of all, there are multiple subfigure packages and no two of them are the same.  More to the point, they don't use the same counters. so to use \setcounter you need to know the counter name used by your package.

Comment: Alternatively, just use minipages and write your own caption.

Comment: The tricky thing here in an automated way is that the figure labeled with `4` is actually the third one.

Comment: Newspapers and magazines sometime use this clockwise order for pictures, but, if you notice, there's never a subcaption in those cases and the picture are only described in the global caption: “Some great movie directors. From upper left clockwise: John Ford, Billy Wilder, Blake Edwards and Mel Brooks.” In your situation, I'd  use the standard order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you use the `subcaption` package to create subfigures, you could proceed as shown in the following example. The answer works by first incrementing and then decrementing the `subfigure` counter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\setlength\textwidth{10cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
% other instructions...
\caption{Subfigure aa} \label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
% other instructions...
\caption{Subfigure bb} \label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}

\stepcounter{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
% other instructions...
\caption{Subfigure dd} \label{fig:d}
\end{subfigure}%
\addtocounter{subfigure}{-2}% 
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
% other instructions...
\caption{Subfigure cc} \label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure with four subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Fantastic! This simple fix works perfectly well! Thank you so much! (Bow), world saver.